# PHP - strpos if it contains anything inside [ ]

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I have the following which works great, but now what I want to do is if a user types `[MAP]` then I want to get the word MAP

I also want allow users to send things like `[MAP = array("LOCATION"=>"Melbourne Australia")]`

and for the PHP to make map a array so I can then send it to a function later on

I currently do the following

```
$map = strpos($stringtocheck, "[MAP]");
```

But the issue here, is if we have a number of [] with different insides like [BOLD], [INSERT] etc then it wont find it and put it in its own $
and also it means we need to know what the array is field with or anything like that

Comment: What kind of a user is going to learn how to send `[MAP = array("LOCATION"=>"Melbourne Australia")]`? If they're going to learn such arcane things, you might as well teach them XML or JSON and parse that.

Comment: its is for a html input form. It will show a map  where the [MAP]. The people that will be using this are people that read the documentation.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @RussellHarrower As a general rule of thumb, your users do not read the documentation. If you are convinced that they will, why not use a pre-existing data format instead of inventing your own?

Comment: The question is how do I get anything between [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex will pull info out of square brackets:

```
$s = 'Yo be [diggin] [my leet] scriptzors!';
$matches = null;
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "diggin"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "my leet"
}
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/erBpuB